# Out indices for different shaped arrays Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to output the index as well as the value for it. I am able to print it within the terminal but I would like to input it into a .txt file. This is the code that I have at the moment. I think it would be helpful to mention that x&y are of shape (528,) and the rest are of shape (528, 528). My current output is also after the section of code.

```
import pencil as pc
import numpy as np

ff = pc.read_var(trimall=True)

x = ff.x
y = ff.y
rho = ff.rho
rhop = ff.rhop
ux = ff.ux
uy = ff.uy

for i in range(528):
    for j in range(528):
        print i,j,rho[i,j],rhop[i,j],ux[i,j],uy[i,j]
```

The output that I am seeing is this, and this is exactly what I want, but written to a .txt file.

527 524 2.5 3.0999421 1.0025754 3.14249721489 0.00104948277254 0.633309939177
527 525 2.5 3.1118420 1.0046337 0.0 0.000712933516338 0.632900900838
527 526 2.5 3.1237420 1.0032471 0.0 0.000648636250453 0.632665342501
527 527 2.5 3.1356420 1.0008004 0.0 0.000442528552988 0.632611938388

Answer (score 2):

You can open a file and write to it (see this [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)):

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as fout:
    for i in range(528):
        for j in range(528):
             fout.write("%d %d %f %f %f %f\n" % (i,j,rho[i,j],rhop[i,j],ux[i,j],uy[i,j]))
```

Or, simply run your script and pipe the output to a file:

```
python script.py >output.txt
```